# Java regex @ notation

Tags: java, regex

I am no expert in Java regex but I cant seem to find any link that will show me what this regex pattern means.

```
([^.@]+)
```

What does this regex pattern describes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@` has no special meaning here; `[^.@]` just means "any character other than `.` or `@`", so `[^.@]+` means "one or more characters that aren't `.` or `@`", and `([^.@]+)` is the same thing but inside a capture-group (so it can be referred to by backreferences and by `Matcher.group(int)`).

For comprehensive documentation of Java regexes, see [the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

That's a group to capture one or more characters that are not an '@' or a '.'

For example

```
"lee@mail.com".replaceAll("([^.@)]","x$1x")
```

would result in

```
xleex@xmailx.xcomx
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson correct, updated answer and added example

Answer (score 0):

Try [Regular Expression Analyzer](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws)

> An online regular expression tool that helps analyzing regular expression structure. The parser will parse it on the fly and produce a tree like representation.